# Distinguishing primitive types from Integer types when parsing from XML file

Tags: java, primitive-types

I'm a student learning about java reflection. I want to dynamically produce methods given a certain class, a method from that class and the parameters of that method. All this data is obtained from an XML file, so there is no way te cast the parameters themselves specifically. To correctly implement my exercice, I have to call the correct function based on the given parameters.

This means I need a way to distinguish between primitive types (like int) and their corresponding Object (like Integer-class). When I parse the parameters, I store them in an Object[] -container.

When I try to determine the class, I always get java.lang.Integer, but never the primitive type. I have searched the internet for several ways to solve this, but I have been unable to find a solution.

Does someone have a better solution or approach at this? Maybe I need to store it differently, but I wouldn't know how (is there something lower and more generic than Object?).

Comment: It's best to *show* what you've tried already. Description is usually not enough. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In your `Object[]` of actual parameter values to give to your method, it is impossible to tell whether value was an `int` or an `Integer`, since the `int` value has been boxed into an `Integer`. The only way to know the difference, it to also supply a `Class<?>[]` with the parameter types. That is also the only way to figure out what the type of a `null` value is supposed to be. In the `Class<?>[]`, an `Integer` parameter is identified by an `Integer.class` object, and an `int` parameter is identified by an `int.class` aka `Integer.TYPE` object.